How to change the active tab in the navigation bar by using flutter_reactive_value as a state management?
I want to change the current page with a push of a button using the indexState value.
I've tried to change the 'index' and 'currentPageIndex' with my 'indexState' with no luck.
I don't know what else to write, I think it is understandable by now.
This is the state manager I'm using.
https://github.com/lukehutch/flutter_reactive_value
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_reactive_value/flutter_reactive_value.dart';

var indexState = ReactiveValueNotifier<int>(0);

void main() => runApp(const NavigationBarApp());

class NavigationBarApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationBarApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: const NavigationExample(),
    );
  }
}

class NavigationExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavigationExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<NavigationExample> createState() => _NavigationExampleState();
}

class _NavigationExampleState extends State<NavigationExample> {
  int currentPageIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            currentPageIndex = index;
          });
        },
        indicatorColor: Colors.amber,
        selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,
        destinations: const <Widget>[
          NavigationDestination(
            selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.home),
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Badge(child: Icon(Icons.notifications_sharp)),
            label: 'Notifications',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: <Widget>[
        /// Home page
        Card(
          shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: SizedBox.expand(
            child: Center(
              child: OutlinedButton(onPressed: () {indexState.value = 1;}, child: Text('go to the second page'))
            ),
          ),
        ),

        Card(
          shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: SizedBox.expand(
            child: Center(
              child: OutlinedButton(onPressed: () {indexState.value = 0;}, child: Text('go to the first page'))
            ),
          ),
        ),

      ][currentPageIndex],
    );
  }
}


